# I'm trying to create a search function that would call a fragment having somewhat similar name than what is searched. Has anyone done this?

Tags: android, search, android-activity, fragment

I already have **dozens** of fragments that each displays its own information. Now - if that's possible -, I'm trying to add a search box that would show a list of relevant fragment names. I'm naming them based on what they contained and launch the one that is clicked.

I'm thinking of using `Activity.getsupportfragmentmanager().findfragmentbyID` function, but the fragment would then need to have been launched within the activity which is far from what I needed.

Could somebody here please point me in the right direction?

Comment: As per my understanding, you can save the names (pre-defined) in an `ArrayList` which would be referred to while searching. Once the user selects a `Fragment`, You will have to dynamically load that specific fragment on your current `Activity`. You'll have to use `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` for this. You can read about it more here https://www.dev2qa.com/android-add-fragment-to-activity-dynamically-example/

Answer (score 0):

Activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByID finds the current fragment sitting in the xml layout in that ID

If you do `FragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.whatever,fragment1).commit()`

and then do `Activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByID(R.id.whatever)`

it will find `fragment1`

then right after you do

```
FragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.whatever,fragment2).commit()
Activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByID(R.id.whatever)
```

it will find `fragment2`

If each fragment has its own ID, this method will work.